# Split a char array in multiple parts in C: unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, char

As a student with a background in Java, C#, a bit of Python and web-based languages, I am currently learning C. For practice I am coding a GTK application to convert a longer text to smaller pieces of text of 140 characters max. This use case is meant to post longer texts on Twitter easily.

So I experimented a bit and the application is working more or less at this moment. However, it regularly shows unexpected behaviour. When inserting text in the GTK interface (TextView) and clicking a button calling the below method, the output put back into the TextView sometimes looks like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni
>   (1/4)
>
> m ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep
>   (2/4)
>
> (0/1981836649)
>
> rehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
>   eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in (3/4)
>
> (0/1763734633)
>
> (1701998412/544044403)
>
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. (4/4)

Or similar when inserting Lorem Ipsum as input. Sometimes it also cuts an entire part (e.g., only the (4/4) part is printed). The expected output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni (1/4)
>
> m ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip > ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep (2/4)
>
> rehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
>   Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in (3/4)
>
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. (4/4)

It applies to the following method, which is hooked to a GTK button:

```
void on_do_tweet_clicked()
{    
    char *text = get_text_from_text_view(g_tv_tweet_text);
    int text_length = strlen(text);
    int tweet_no = text_length / 130 + (text_length % 130 != 0);
    char tweets[(int) tweet_no][140 * sizeof(char*)];

    for (int i = 0; i < tweet_no; i++)
    {
        char *tweet = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 140); 
        if (tweet_no != 1) {
            if (i + 1 == tweet_no) {
                strcpy(tweet, &text[i * 130]);
            } else {
                strncpy(tweet, &text[i * 130], 130);
            }
            strcat(tweet, " (%d/%i)\n\0");
            sprintf(tweets[i], tweet, i + 1, tweet_no);
        } else {
            strcpy(tweet, &text[i * 130]);
            sprintf(tweets[i], tweet);
        }

        free(tweet); 
    }

    free(text);

    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer((GtkTextView *) g_tv_tweet_text);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tweets) / sizeof(tweets[0]); i++)
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(buffer, tweets[i], strlen(tweets[i]));
    }

    memset(tweets, 0, sizeof(tweets));
}
```

I did some research on the problem and I suspect it has to do with either an problem with encodings or a problem related to pointers. However, my searches on the web did not result in a solution and my knowledge of C is still too limited to draw my own conclusions.

So here's the question: could anyone explain why this method is showing this behaviour and give me a hint on how to solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `char *tweet = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 140);` - why is `sizeof(char*)` used here?

Comment: Function `strncpy` is not intended to be used with C strings. In general case, it does not zero terminate the target buffer. In your code I see `strncpy` folowed by `strcat` - this is exactly the case when `strncpy`'s failure to trerminate the buffer will result in nonsense.

Comment: I love valgrind. I'll bet you will too if you make friends with it.

Comment: @AnT (1) I thought maybe this was a better practice as I am allocating based on the environment (32 or 64-bit)

Comment: `sprintf(tweets[i], tweet)` - this looks like a dangerous equivalent of `strcpy`. Why would you do it, if you already knew about `strcpy`? What exactly did you attempt to achieve with that `sprintf`?

Comment: @AnT (2) Ah, thanks. I thought that was the way to copy a certain amount of characters (130, in this case). I will google some more on how to do that, then.

Comment: @AnT (3) Now you highlight it, I don't know why I put it there either.

Comment: @Luc van der Zandt: If you want to use `strncpy` for limited-length string copying, don't forget to manually add zero-terminator to the result.

Comment: @AnT: Ah, right. So I can use `strncpy` there but with a zero-terminator added? So, after `strncpy(tweet, &text[i * 130], 130);` I add `tweet[131] = '\0';` or something?

Comment: Um, my bad, I mean `tweet[130] = '\0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AnT I got it working. The final code is:

```
void on_do_tweet_clicked()
{    
    char *text = get_text_from_text_view(g_tv_tweet_text);
    int text_length = strlen(text);
    int tweet_no = text_length / 130 + (text_length % 130 != 0);
    char tweets[(int) tweet_no][140 * sizeof(char)];

    for (int i = 0; i < tweet_no; i++)
    {
        char *tweet = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 140); 
        if (tweet_no != 1) {
            if (i + 1 == tweet_no) {
                strcpy(tweet, &text[i * 130]);
            } else {
                strncpy(tweet, &text[i * 130], 130);
            }
            tweet[130] = '\0';
            strcat(tweet, " (%d/%i)\n");
            sprintf(tweets[i], tweet, i + 1, tweet_no);
        } else {
            strcpy(tweets[i], &text[i * 130]);
        }

        free(tweet); 
    }

    free(text);

    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer((GtkTextView *) g_tv_tweet_text);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tweets) / sizeof(tweets[0]); i++)
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(buffer, tweets[i], strlen(tweets[i]));
    }

    memset(tweets, 0, sizeof(tweets));
}
```